# How would you catch python Exception inside an except clause

Tags: python, file, exception, try-catch

How would you catch exception within exception in python ?

Consider the following case

```
bak_filename = filename + ".bak"
#This try is needed because if bak_filename existed, rename will fail
try:
   os.rename(filename, bak_filename)
except WindowsError:
   #However, os.remove may still fail e.g. file in use. How would you handle this exception within except clause ?
   #try and except around this os.remove?  
   os.remove(bak_filename)

   os.rename(filename, bak_filename)
```

Any thought of :

1. Rewriting to avoid double **try**?
2. Not necessarily this example, but in some case we cannot rewrite, how would you handle double **try** ?

Comment: What's wrong with putting `try/except` around `os.remove()`?

Comment: Just the back of my head from some experience and reading that it would be messy and difficult to debug afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

A solution to avoid all this exception wrapping would be to use [`shutil.move`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move)

```
shutil.move(filename, bak_filename)
```

> If the destination already exists but is not a directory, it may be overwritten depending on os.rename() semantics.
>
> If the destination is on the current filesystem, then os.rename() is used. Otherwise, src is copied to dst using copy_function and then removed. In case of symlinks, a new symlink pointing to the target of src will be created in or as dst and src will be removed.

So it basically does what you're trying to do, but in a library which is available on all python distros.

Note that the performance may be bad if the file is big and the target file exists *and* `os.rename` refuses to overwrite it (completely depends on the operating system but for instance Windows will refuse to rename over an existing file), because the fallback when `os.rename` throws `OSError` is copying the source *then* deleting. The implementation doesn't try to remove the file *then* rename again, because if `rename` fails, Python assumes that we're trying to rename across filesystems, and a copy+delete is in order in that case (this is exactly how Unix `mv` works).

```
try:
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
except OSError:
    if os.path.islink(src):
        ...
    else:
        copy_function(src, real_dst)
        os.unlink(src)
```

To workaround that possible file existence, a prior `os.remove` call wrapped in a `try/except OSError` statement could be done.

```
try:
   os.remove(bak_filename)
except OSError:
   pass
shutil.move(filename, bak_filename)  # or os.rename(filename, bak_filename)
```

Of course if `bak_filename` is locked/not deletable, an exception can still be raised by `shutil.mode`. Also note that if we tried to delete the target file, `os.rename` will be as good as `shutil.move`. If the target file could not be deleted, the operation can't succeed anyway.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting package, but I don't have admin permission to install packages at will and need to stick with **os**

Comment: you don't need to install this. This is _built-in_.

Answer (score 0):

You can read more on [Exception Chaining](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/). But, that's for Python 3

In Python 2, you can store your exception in a variable, then raise it again explicitly like this:

```
try:
    do something
except Exception as e:
    try:
        do something again
    except:
        pass
    raise e
```